# Как посмотреть/декодировать исходный код игры написанный на Lua?

Tags: кодировка, компиляция, lua, декомпиляция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть исходный код игры написанный на Lua, как посмотреть/декодировать код, чтобы отображался в нормальном формате?
В данный момент один и тот же код отображается вот так:

Нотпад++:

`LJi  +  7 7  >+ % >: 2  : G  ÀÀ
childrendata/image/frame.png
framenew`

Sublime:

1b4c 4a01 0269 0001 0302 0500 0c2b 0100
0037 0100 0137 0101 0110 0200 003e 0102
012b 0101 0025 0203 003e 0102 023a 0102
0032 0100 003a 0104 0047 0001 0005 c002
c00d 6368 696c 6472 656e 1964 6174 612f
696d 6167 652f 6672 616d 652e 706e 670a
6672 616d 6508 6e65 770a 7375 7065 7247

Answer (score 3):

Есть специальная тула для этого: [LuaDec](http://luadec51.luaforge.net/). Но вопрос в версии исходников. Вообще надо посмотреть [тут](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools) и посмотреть, какой из декомпиляторов тебе поможет.

Аналогичный вопрос на английском SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743684/best-tools-for-decompiling-lua-bytecode

Comment: Можешь на пальцах объяснить как что делать? Не могу понять как пользоваться LuaDec

Comment: А на чем застрял? Я сам не пользовался (не было нужды), но мб подскажу.